# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0} (1-x)^{\frac 1x}$

Tags: limits

How do you evaluate this limit?
$$\lim_{x\to 0} (1-x)^{\frac 1x}$$

I looked at it graphically ([here is the graph](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20%281-x%29%5E%281%2Fx%29&x=0&y=0)), but it doesn't look like the limit is any nice number. Does anyone know how to find this?

Answer (score 5):

One of the definitions of $e^y$ is $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{y}n\right)^n$. In your case, replace $x$ by $1/n$, we then have
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(1-x\right)^{1/x} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\dfrac1n\right)^n = e^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the answer is $e^{-1}$. If you want to see it without remembering the particular definition for $e^x$ mentioned in the @user17762 solution, a good technique for calculating these sorts of limits where two parts are "fighting" with each other is to force it into a form where you can use L'Hôpital's rule. L'Hôpital's rule works with quotients, and we have an exponent, so we have to use logarithms to turn it into a quotient. Observe:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1 - x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x\to 0} \exp{\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}} = \exp \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x} = \exp \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{-1}{1-x}}{1} = \exp (-1) = e^{-1} \text{.}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $y = 1/x$, then $y \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$. And

$$\lim _{y\to \infty} \Big(1 - \frac{1}{y}\Big)^y = \frac{1}{e}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you define $e = \lim_{x \to \infty} (1 + 1/x)^x$ then the calculation is not so bad. However if you define $e$ in some other way, say as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/n!$ then the proof will be harder.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure the limit is $e^{-1}$.  In fact $(1+\frac1n)^n\rightarrow e$.